# Kerberos on WSS 3.0?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss, kerberos

I'm trying to follow this guide on a new WSS 3.0 install on a Windows 2008 R2 VM to get kerberos working.

First off, is is possible to set up an SSP (shared Services provider) in WSS 3.0?

I ask, because I'm on this step:

STSADM.exe -o SetSharedWebServiceAuthn -negotiate

getting ***missing operation name or the operation name is invalid***... is this because I'm not running MOSS?

on another step I'm trying to change security settings on  IIS WAMREG Admin  but they are all grayed out.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command does indeed not exist for WSS. Because Shared Services are a part of MOSS and not of WSS. Since you have WSS you don't need to set up the authentication method for the SSPs (they don't even exist in your farm).

For the IIS WAMREG Admin problem i have no idea (do you have enough rights?)

---

STSADM commands for WSS: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287799(office.12).aspx
STSADM commands for MOSS: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262643(v=Office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks. Figured out the WAMREG issue - apparently in win 2008 R2 you have to change ownership on the registry entry first. Still have issues where I can't get Kerberos to work on my new install - setspns are set, everything looks fine, but just not working.